# Comment Form Custom Form Field

Tags: comments, comment-form

Is it possible to add custom form fields to the EE comment form? What I would like to do is to require people to be logged in members to post but allow them to comment anonymously.

If I add a checkbox with a "Reply Anonymously" option it doesn't record the checkbox state in the exp_comments table.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use custom fields in the comment form but you can repurpose any of the [**native fields**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/index.html#comment-submission-form) to use as needed.

You might look at repurposing the "location" or "url" field and passing your value to that column in the database..

Comment: It seems that if you are logged in, the only field that can be written to in a comment form is the comment text area. Repurposing the other fields doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Post the code you are testing to http://www.pastie.org

Comment: Hi Anna - it's at [http://pastie.org/6412039](http://pastie.org/6412039).

Comment: So the checkbox just isn't working at all meaning you can't check it or you can check it but the data isn't passing to the DB?

Comment: You can check it but the data isn't passed into the DB.

Comment: Try the location field, any data passed? Try hardcoding an entry_ID too on the comment tag.

Comment: No go, and I was hardcoding an entry_id. I assume it's a form of data protection since those fields are related to the member account or simply the logged-in autofill always overrides.

Comment: The fields are specific to comments and the data is stored with comments. You can prepopulate with member data but that's the only relation. Sounds like something just isn't set up correctly. I've used these fields this way before with success. Not sure how best to help you on this one without getting into your EE build.

Comment: Did anyone manage to work this one out. It seems the 'location' field will only work if it's a non-logged in member account, otherwise it's pulled from the users profile.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet, after checking Devot-ee (why didn't I look there first) I found a recent addon called 'Custom comment fields' (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-comment-fields) which allows you to add some simple custom fields (Text input, Textarea, Safecracker File) to EE comments module posts. I then used this as a way to add the ability for logged in users to specify if there wished to post a specific comment anonymously.

I added a new custom field using this addon called {comment_anonymously} and then set this as a checkbox field in the {exp:comment:form}

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment_anonymously" value="y" /> 
    Post my comment anonymously
</label>
```

Then in the {exp:comment:entries} loop, I used a conditional on the custom comment field to display the users name or not:

```
Posted by 
{if '{comment_anonymously}' == 'y'}
    Anonymous 
    {if logged_in_group_id == '1'}
        (<em>{name}</em>)
    {/if}
{if:else}
    {name}
{/if}
```

Note that I've also placed in a conditional for if a Super Admin is looking to show the users actual name for easy verification.

Cheers
Brendan